# Forgot Password Redirect - Need to goto B2C Login Page instead of CRM Portal

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

So I have a CRM Portal Sign In button which forwards me to the B2C SignIn Page. It has a "Forgot Password" link. When that does its job, it redirects me back to CRM Portal which says "Sign in failed.". Which is obvious because the user didn't actually signin and thus no token was sent back.

What I want is for the user to be redirected to the B2C Signin page and then after logging in to be redirected back to the CRM Portal as successfully logged in.

How can I do this? I can't see any redirectURI in the PasswordReset policy endpoint URL. Should I just fudge it and hardcode the redirectURI in it? Where do I do that as the "forgot your password" link doesn't show up anywhere to edit. I used generic html template found [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-AzureBlobStorage-Client/blob/master/sample_templates/wingtip/unified.html) for the signuporsignin custom policy

Comment: Is this a custom app that implements the CRM portal?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett It is out of the box portal but customizable. It's a customized Dynamics Portal which is SaaS offering.

Comment: Redirects to CRMPORTALURL/Account/Login/ExternalAuthenticationFailed and then says "Sign in Failed".

Answer (score 0):

Have to configure ValidIssuers in federation as shown https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c#password-reset with the passwordreset and signin policies URL. (comma separated)